# Javascript String Array-Like-Object behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image: Adding new value to string]

When I run above code in Chrome dev console, I do not get any error. But when same code runs via `js` loaded on a webpage I receive this exception -
 `Cannot create property 'name' on string 'some string'`

Can someone please tell me why there is different behaviour in above 2 cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webpage must be running that snippet of code in strict mode, in which assigning to properties of a string will throw an error:

```js
'use strict';
const str = 'foo';
str.bar = 'bar';
```

In sloppy mode, it'll just fail silently:

```js
const str = 'foo';
str.bar = 'bar';
```

Comment: But if you console.log(str.bar) you get undefined. It is not valid to add a property to a value object.

Comment: Indeed, it's not valid, it just won't throw an error in sloppy mode: `In sloppy mode, it'll just fail silently`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are a value objects as in they have a value not a reference to an instance of an object, they cannot have properties set with a["name"] like reference objects can.

a[3] is the 4th character in the string, a[0] being the first.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see this case

```
const a = "a"
Object.isFrozen(a) // true
const b = new String("b")
Object.isFrozen(b) // false
```

From this section, we could see that `String` objects are not necessarily frozen. Only those string literals are frozen (I think it's because they are shared in a pool. If they are not frozen, you can create properties on one place to affect the code elsewhere) However, the explicitly constructed `String` objects are independent from the pool, thus not frozen.